# How do I stop gedit from opening anything?

Tags: 11.10, gedit, default-programs

I use gVim all the time and open all sorts of plain text files, source codes and virtually anything that is readable with gVim.

Ubuntu however decides that I should use gedit!

I got searching and I found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27823/how-do-i-set-gvim-as-my-default-text-editor-instead-of-gedit) that correctly makes ubuntu open my plain text files with gVim, but no luck with source files. I set both

```
sudo update-alternatives --config editor
sudo update-alternatives --config gnome-text-editor
```

to gVim, but still it uses gedit for source files.

Not to mention most of what you find on the internet say "right click->Open with->Always use this application" to set the default app for each of your file types. I'm fine with that, <del>but in the new ubuntu (11.10) that option is simply not there anymore.</del> but it could get rather cumbersome.

I went for uninstalling gedit, but it told me if I do, *future updates will not include new items in The Ubuntu Desktop System set*.

My question is, how can I tell ubuntu to change the default application of all those things that open with gedit to gVim?

If no such thing is possible (which would be the stupidest thing ever), would I really miss much if I uninstall gedit and forget about those mentioned *new items*?

Comment: Have a look [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/72535/creating-desktop-files-to-use-on-the-open-with-other-application-tab) to solve the application missing on the open with another program tab.

Comment: @brunopereira81, I had seen that, but that is not what I'm asking. I do see gVim in the Open with options. My problem is I can't set it as default application.

Comment: sorry miss understood it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On 11.10 `defaults.list` is under `/etc/gnome/defaults.list`

- Open `defaults.list` using any text editor.
- Replace `text/plain=gedit.desktop`  with `text/plain=gvim.desktop`
- Save and close.

Right click on any text file and you will see like this:-

[image]

It works for me :)

Comment: Great fix! A `%s/gedit/gvim/g` (replace gedit with gvim) did all that I wanted to do all at once! Thanks

Comment: It would be interesting to see how your menu and dialog looks like, Shabbaz.

Comment: @Jo-ErlendSchinstad, pretty normal, what do you mean? It's just the editor I changed (Well, I lied, I removed the mail indicator (I would have removed that change user indicator too, but that is connected to the restart/shutdown button (!!!)), I also removed autohide of the sidebar, but it all still "looks" pretty normal)

Comment: To make the change user specific and not system-wide, add `text/plain=gvim.desktop` to the `[Default Applications]` section in `.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list`.

Comment: On 18.04 [seems on `/usr/share/applications/`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/154906/which-default-list-should-i-modify-for-default-applications-and-what-are-the-dif#comment1828553_223921).

Answer (score 1):

> Not to mention most of what you find on the internet says right click->Open width->Always >use this application to set the default app for each of your file types. I'm fine with >that, but in the new ubuntu (11.10) that option is simply not there anymore.

I had this same problem with getting LibreOffice to recognize .xlsx files.  Right-click on the file you want to open, click properties, and go to the 'Open With' tab.  There, you can select an application and there should be an option in the bottom right  to 'Set as default'

Hope it helps!

Comment: Like I said, in the new ubuntu, it's not there. That "Set as default" button is just not there!!

Comment: It's  - right click > PROPERTIES > open with..

Comment: @Shahbaz How about my answer? have you tried?

Comment: Ah, I didn't read carefully. Yes I see it now, but the accepted answer proved to be much better. Thanks for telling me though :)

Answer (score 0):

The option to choose what program to open an application with, *is* there, as can be seen in this screenshot.

[image]

Or, you can open the Properties dialog (the one called Egenskaper in my screenshot) and choose Open With:

[image]

Then you can choose to show other applications:

[image]

When you add another application, then it will appear in the list to open with, as shown in the first screenshot, and you can choose to open with that application by default.