# Programatically modify file associations using standard interface (cases where mimetype does not matter)

Tags: command-line, 20.04, lubuntu, settings, file-format

I know that I can use `xdg-mime default codium.desktop text/plain` to change association for `text\plain` mimetype ( [Programatically modify file associations using standard interface (using mimetype)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/791935/programatically-modify-file-associations-using-standard-interface-using-mimetyp) )

But for example `file --mime-type -b index.ts` reports also `text\plain` and `xdg-mime query default text/plain` reports `codium.desktop`

But index.ts file is opened by "Qt Linguist". Unlike say wat.txt file that is opened as expected, by Codium.

As result `xdg-mime default codium.desktop text/plain` has no effect whatsoever.

Is there some standard CLI option to override whatever sets such default? I am fine with it being Ubuntu specific or even Lubuntu specific. Though I would prefer it as broad as possible.

I know that I can set settings to something sane with GUI - but I want to add it to system setup scripts and avoid doing it manually on every system reinstall.

I now discovered `~/.config/mimeapps.list` that now contains line: `text/vnd.qt.linguist=codium.desktop;` triggered by manual adding file association (no idea why .ts file is captured by Qt but...).

Running `xdg-mime default codium.desktop text/vnd.qt.linguist` liberated .ts file from Qt tyranny and now opens in Codium as I want to happen with TypeScript files (fortunately I do not care about qt.linguist files at all, so misclassification is not affecting me)

So how can I see actual mime type? In cases where `file --mime-type -b` fails?

Is `text/vnd.qt.linguist` a mimetype?

---

I noticed that file properties GUI is displaying MIME type diverging from one reported by `file --mime-type -b`. How can I get proper MIME type without using GUI?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were missing the use of `xdg-mime` on a specific file.

**How can I see actual mime type?**

Try

```
$ xdg-mime query filetype index.ts
```

or

```
$ mimetype index.ts
```

It seems `file` examines the contents of the file, while `xdg-mime` uses a combination of methods to determine the MIME type, including some times calls to `file`.
I didn't find so far a specification of the algortihm used by `xdg-mime` to decide on the MIME type, but this info is so far enough for your purpose, I guess.

**Is `text/vnd.qt.linguist` a mimetype?**

[Yes](https://reposcope.com/mimetype/text/vnd.qt.linguist).

**Related**:

1. [Why the difference between the results with "file --mime-type" and "xdg-mime query filetype"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/844864/why-the-difference-between-the-results-with-file-mime-type-and-xdg-mime-que)
2. [What is the relationship between MIME types and File .extensions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7517/what-is-the-relationship-between-mime-types-and-file-extensions?rq=1)
3. https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xdg/shared-mime-info/-/issues/10
4. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/565202/kde-is-not-saving-a-mime-type-file-association

Comment: `xdg-mime query filetype Bicycle.validator.mapcss` worked perfectly. Due to some weird design I need to wait 23 hours to award bounty.