# I cannot set as default program libre office instead of wps for docx files only

Tags: libreoffice, default, doc

I cannot set as default program libre office instead of wps for docx files only. I can set libre office as default for doc files though. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a fresh re-instalation of both libre and wps I can now set libre as default through the right click menu

Answer (score 2):

### Changing default application in GUI

1. Right-click your *.docx* file.
2. Click in *Properties*.
3. Select *Open With* tab.
4. Select application from lists *Related Applications* or *Other Application*.
5. Click in *Set as default*.
6. Close *Properties* window.

If you want to rollback your change:

1. Follow steps *1 to 3*.
2. Click in *Reset*.
3. Close *Properties* window.

Comment: I have taken the above steps but wps office remains default only for docx files.

Answer (score 1):

Pulled from [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/223921/421237), use your editor of choice (and sudo/gksudo, thanks [Weboide](https://askubuntu.com/users/154/weboide)) to modify `/usr/share/applications/defaults.list` to have the following line:

```
application/docx=wps-office-wps.desktop
```

For all the other file types relating to Office programs (e.g. xls, doc), you can set a different editor e.g.

```
application/xlsx=libreoffice-writer.desktop
```

Comment: You forgot to mention, you'll need to run the editor as root: `gksudo gedit /usr/share/applications/defaults.list` is one way to do it using gedit on a regular ubuntu install.

Comment: I have opened the editor but I am not sure how to modify the line correctly to set libre office as the defaukt program

Comment: @Andros, what is currently shown next to the "application/docx" and "application/doc" lines in that file?

Comment: It shows "application/wps-office.docx=wps-office-wps.desktop" and "application/wps-office.doc=wps-office-wps.desktop" thoug doc files has been changed to libre office as deafault through the right click menu

Comment: If you are still experiencing the doc files being opened with wps rather than libreoffice, you will need to edit the defaults.list file as above.
It is possible that the Nautilus (right-click) file open option is controlled by another file, but the defaults.list file overrides it.